# Let $F$ be a field, and let $f(x)\in F[x]$ be a polynomial of prime degree. Suppose for every field extension $K$ of $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

**Let $F$ be a field, and let $f(x)\in F[x]$ be a polynomial of prime degree.
Suppose for every field extension $K$ of $F$ that if $f$ has a root in $K$,
then $f$ splits over $K$. Prove that either $f$ is irreducible over $F$ or $f$
has a root (and hence splits) in $F$.**

Suppose $f$ is reducible over $F$ then there exists a $a$ in $F$ such that $f(x)=(x-a)g(x)$ which means that $f$ has a root in $F$. I can not understand what I am doing wrong, someone could help me please (where do I have to use the polynomial has prime degree?)? Thank you.

Comment: That's not what reducibility means; it just means that $f$ has some nontrivial factorization $f = gh$, and neither $g$ nor $h$ are guaranteed to be linear.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, there I have the error, but since $f$ has prime degree some of these factors have to be linear no?

Comment: @user424241 No. $\text{deg}(gh)=\text{deg}(g) + \text{deg}( h)$. So the prime number is not sufficient to conclude the one of them has to be linear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Think about the degree of each irreducible factor of $f$, by considering the degree of the field extension obtained by adjoining a root.

Stronger hint:

> Let $K$ be a splitting field of $f$ over $F$.  Can you prove that the degree of every irreducible factor of $f$ is $[K:F]$?

Full proof:

> Let $K$ be a splitting field of $f$ over $F$.  If $g$ is any irreducible factor of $f$, then $K'=F[x]/(g(x))$ is a field extension of $F$ with a root of $g$ and hence a root of $f$, and therefore $f$ splits over $K'$.  Thus $K'$ is a splitting field of $f$ over $F$ and is isomorphic to $K$ over $F$.  Thus $\deg g=[K':F]=[K:F]$.  Since this is true of every irreducible factor of $f$, $\deg f=n[K:F]$ where $n$ is the number of irreducible factors of $f$ (counting multiplicity).  Since $\deg f$ is prime, this means we either have $[K:F]=1$ (i.e., $f$ has a root in $F$) or $n=1$ (i.e., $f$ is irreducible).